# Prove that the order of $A$'s rows does not affect the result of $A^T\cdot A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let us consider the following matrix
$$A=
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 2 \\
5 & 6 \\
3 & 4
\end{array}\right)$$
I noticed that the result of the product:
$$A^T\cdot A=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
35 & 44 \\
44 & 56
\end{array}\right)$$
does not change if we rearrange the order of $A$'s rows. Is it always true, for all matrices $A$, that $A^T\cdot A$ doesn't change if we rearrange the order of $A$'s rows?

Comment: Row switching can be done by multiplying by [these matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Row-switching_transformations). If $E$ is one such matrix, we have that $E^T=E$ and $E^2=I$. Then switching rows of $A$ would be $EA$. This gives $(EA)^T(EA)=A^TE^TEA=A^TE^2A=A^TA$. And, well, permutations of rows can be obtained by composing multiple row switching operations.

Comment: Over the reals, at least, the entries of $A^TA$ are just the inner-products of the columns of $A$ so the row-order does not matter.  [True over all fields but inner products don't always make sense.]

Comment: If $A$ is $n\times m$ and an $n\times n$ matrix $U$ such that $U^TU=I$ we get that $(UA)^T(UA)=A^T(U^TU)A=A^TA.$ The matrix which re-arranges rows is just such a $U.$ Essentially, such a $U$ has as its columns an orthonormal basis of $n\times n$ space, and $U$ is some isometry if$n$-dimensional space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Rearranging the rows of $A$", say exchanging the last two corresponds to the multiplication from the left with the corresponding permutation matrix. So consider
$$
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 3 &4 \\ 5 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
=
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\ & & 1\\ &1
\end{bmatrix}}_{:=\Pi}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 5 & 6 \\ 3 &4 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\Pi A\ ,
$$
then $B^TB=(\Pi A)^T(\Pi A)=A^T(\Pi^T\Pi)A=A^T(\Pi^{-1}\Pi)A=A^T\; I\; A=A^TA$.

For any other permutation matrix (a matrix with exact one $1$ entry in each row and in each column) $\Pi$ we have also $\Pi^T=\Pi^{-1}$, and the same argument applies.
Also in the general case when $A$ is some $m\times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the multiplication $A^TA$, cell by cell, then

$$\begin{align*}
A^TA &= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 5 & 3 \\
2 & 6 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
5 & 6 \\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
+ \begin{pmatrix}
5 \\ 6
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}
+ \begin{pmatrix}
3 \\ 4
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}\\
&= \left(a_{1,*}\right)^T a_{1,*} + \left(a_{2,*}\right)^T a_{2,*} + \left(a_{3,*}\right)^T a_{3,*} \tag{*}
\end{align*}$$

$(*)$ Here $a_{i,*}$ [denotes the whole $i$th row of matrix $A$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Notation).

Permuting rows of $A$ would have no impact, since the sum of matrices on the $(*)$ line is commutative.